# splitting the text, make the view of text false in textview

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a text file, that i want to display it's text in the number of text views,that i set their texts in run time.

here is my code, that i use for my program:

```
while(text.length() > 0)
    {
        text = text.trim();
        int index = text.indexOf("L1");
        int index2 = 0;
        temp = "";
        if(index > -1 && index == 0)
        {
            index2 = text.indexOf("/L1");
            temp = text.substring(index + 2, index2);
            temp.trim();
            t = temp.toCharArray();
            text = text.substring(index2 + 3, text.length());
            index = text.indexOf("\r\n");
            while(index > -1 && index == 0)
            {
                temp += "\r\n";
                text = text.substring(index + 2, text.length());
                index = text.indexOf("\r\n");
            }
            temp = String.valueOf(t);
        }
        else
        {
            index = text.indexOf("L2");
            if(index > -1 && index == 0)
            {
                index2 = text.indexOf("/L2");
                temp = text.substring(index + 2, index2);
                text = text.substring(index2 + 3, text.length());
                index = text.indexOf("\r\n");
                while(index > -1 && index == 0)
                {
                    temp += "\r\n";
                    text = text.substring(index + 2, text.length());
                    index = text.indexOf("\r\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                index = text.indexOf("List");
                if(index > -1 && index == 0)
                {
                    index2 = text.indexOf("/List");
                    temp = text.substring(index + 4, index2);
                    text = text.substring(index2 + 5, text.length());
                    index = text.indexOf("\r\n");
                    while(index > -1 && index == 0)
                    {
                        temp += "\r\n";
                        text = text.substring(index + 2, text.length());
                        index = text.indexOf("\r\n");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    text = text.trim();
                    index = text.indexOf("Plain");
                    if(index > -1 && index == 0)
                    {
                        index2 = text.indexOf("/Plain");
                        temp = text.substring(index + 5, index2);
                        text = text.substring(index2 + 6, text.length());
                        index = text.indexOf("\r\n");
                        while(index > -1 && index == 0)
                        {
                            temp += "\r\n";
                            text = text.substring(index + 2, text.length());
                            index = text.indexOf("\r\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    for(int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++)
    {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(Farsi.Convert(texts[i]));
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/naz.ttf");
        tv.setTypeface(font);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        tv.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        tv.setLayoutParams(params);
        linearLayout.addView(tv);
    }
    layout.addView(linearLayout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    this.addContentView(layout, p);
}
```

i use some auxiliary words(such as "L1" and "/L1") for some reasons in text file, that delete them in run time. but, when i run the program, in the output the text that shown in text views, is not in right style, i want to align it to right, but in the output there are some additional text, that aren't in the input text file.

in the 2 images in below, i attach the output with and without the auxiliary words in the input text file.

output with auxiliary words:

[image: output with auxiliary words:]

output without auxiliary words, in this state, i set the content of layout using, "setContentView" function, and read the whole file instead of split text using auxiliary words index. in this state, the input does not contain the auxiliary words.

[image: output without auxiliary words]

what is the problem friends?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all:
use `String.split()` to split your string.
It works like this, if you have a string A,B,C and you use `myString.split(,)` output will be an array of substrings i.e [A,B,C].
But this is useful in your case if you can have the same delimiter ie L1 and L2 will be same.

Second: You can use `android:gravity="right"` in the `textview` of your `layout.xml`. This will resolve the issue of strings being aligned to left.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i set gravity with the this line : "tv.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);", but it does not worked for me! the problem is that, when i use the substring function, and make new text views with these texts, the output will been such the output image in the post